# split extended classes over different files (php)

Tags: php, class, class-design, abstract-class

#### Szenario

I got a class as extend of an abstract class. The abstract class loads my files & extensions with their methods [(link to pastebin for abstract class)](http://pastebin.com/sURA8qyg).

This gets called in my extends class like this (shortened & simplified - typos are only here at the Q-code):

```
class Pagination extends Pagination_Base
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // loads the file "first.class.php" in the abstract class
        parent::load_file( 'first' ); 
        // stores the class as object in the abstract class, so we can access the methods and properties
        parent::load_extension( new oxoFirst() );
    }
}
```

#### Problem/Question

Now i got the error *"Cannot redeclare class {$classname}"*.

I want to use my abstract class but still be able to move classes that contain extensions into separate files. Is there any way to do this?

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `include_once` instead of `include` in the `load_file` function.

Comment: As easy as things can be... Thanks a lot!